# CDetailView don't show properly Chtml::link's HTML data

Tags: yii, yii-chtml, cdetailview

i use Chtml::link in one CDetailView.

```
array(
                    'label'=>'Images',
                    'type'=>'html',
                    'value'=> CHtml::link('<i class="fa fa-tag"></i>','#',array('data-target'=>'#myModal','class'=>'tag','data-toggle'=>'modal')),
                ),
```

But html properly not generated. it only add few property like below

```
<a class="tag" href="#"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i></a>
```

How can i add all property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array(
  'label'=>'Images',
  'type'=>'html',
  'value'=> CHtml::link('<i class="fa fa-tag"></i>','#',array('data-target'=>'#myModal','class'=>'tag','data-toggle'=>'modal')),
),
```

change 'type'=>'html',       to
       'type'=>'raw',

After changing the code its look like below block

```
array (
  'label' => 'Images',
  'type'  => 'raw',
  'value' => CHtml::link('<i class="fa fa-tag"></i>','#',array('data-target'=>'#myModal','class'=>'tag','data-toggle'=>'modal')),
),
```